# MySQL select row range for export/view

Tags: mysql, select, rows

I have a 9TB MySQL table I need to export to export to excel for further analysis.  There are over 4.8 million rows in the table. When I export data using "SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE path" the resultant file is to large for Excel to injest.  Is there a way to export only 1 million rows at a time? For example export 1-1,000,000, then export 1,000,001 - 2,000,000, 2,000,001-3,000,000, etc.

I need to review all the data in the rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIMIT` in the select statement.

for the first set of `100000` records, use

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 100000 INTO OUTFILE path
```

and for the next set of `100000` records, use

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100001, 100000 INTO OUTFILE path
```

and so on ...

And for each of the sets, you can use a separate out file to manage.

***Note***:
1. Limit range: 0 - 100000: fetches starting 100,000 records.
2. Limit range: 100001 - 100000: fetches next 100,000 records starting from 100001st record.

Comment: I know this is exactly what the OP asked, but hopefully Excel will then be at good will about several files making one large. ;)

Comment: It all depends upon the size of each row and total number of records. OP already mentioned that there exist about 4.8 millions of records. Sure it would be high load for excel to load all at once.

Comment: Just googled a bit (this topic touches a job I applied to) and it seems you have to do a new sheet per file...OP will find out and manage I guess. ;)

Comment: The first command SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1, 100000 INTO OUTFILE path; works fine. When I input the second command SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100001, 2000000 INTO OUTFILE path"  I get 2 million records instead of 1 million.  Am I missing something in my command sytax.  It appears that the command is ignoring the number the number to start at.  I am using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Ok... others too should work. There was a typo error in my answer on `LIMIT` value ranges. Corrected. Please check.

Comment: That did the trick.  The first value selects what row you want to begin with and the second value is the number of records you want.  Thank you for your assistance.